# Returns sorted a multidimensional array in Java (android)

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have two questions that are linked.

In Java can't create associative arrays.

I need to use this funciton:
arrayOrderBy(arr Data, str Field = '' str OrderBy = 'asc', bool NumericShort) and return sorted a multidimensional array.

I have seen that it is possible to "create" associative arrays with HashMap /Map:
http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.es/2012/12/how-to-sort-hashmap-java-by-key-and-value.html
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-sort-a-map-in-java/

But only works with key-value.

But I need more "columns". For example:

User: Id, Name, mail, ...

**How I can create an associative array of this type and then sort it by type without creating a style class "User" (with its attributes)?**

Comment: I would suggest you to use POJO for Information and store into ArrayLIst. Here you can sort your info as your need

Comment: Perhaps using a local database might suit your needs. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db